# xampp control new install

Tags: windows, xampp

Everytime I install XAMPP on my new laptop I get this popup when closing:

[enter error when i close xampp control panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0C7I6.png)

and this in the error log and I have no clue why

````
AH00558: httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::798c:c498:a91e:b3f0. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Fri May 29 22:49:30.682665 2020] [core:warn] [pid 9748:tid 836] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Fri May 29 22:49:30.694634 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 9748:tid 836] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Fri May 29 22:49:30.696594 2020] [:emerg] [pid 9748:tid 836] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting```
````